# Integrate $ \int_0^{\phi_0} \arctan \sqrt{\frac{\cos \phi+1}{\alpha \cos \phi +\beta}}d\phi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

EDIT/UPDATE: I DO NOT NEED A SOLUTION. SEE SOS440 COMMENT FOR A FULL DETAILED SOLUTION.

Hi I am trying to integrate
$$
\int_0^{\phi_0} \arctan \sqrt{\frac{\cos \phi+1}{\alpha \cos \phi +\beta}}d\phi,
$$
where $\alpha > |\beta|$ and min$_{0\leq \phi \leq \phi_0}(\alpha\cos \phi +\beta)\geq 0$.

I think this class of integrals is from the early 2000's mathematics journals, however I may be mistaken.  Any literature on this would be very helpful as well.

Some ideas I had were trying to use trig identities to first re-write the square root expression by using
$$
\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos \phi)=\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2},\quad \alpha\cos\phi+\beta=\alpha+\beta-2\alpha \sin^2\frac{\phi}{2},
$$
however I am not sure where to go from here.  Thank you for reading.

Comment: I have been working with exactly that version of Coxeter's integral and found that it is directly related to the family of *Ahmed's integral*.

Comment: @sos440 Do you have literature on this or a solution?  I am not familiar with Coxeter integrals surprisingly.  How long they have been around?? Thank you very much for this information

Comment: I think [this document](http://cfile29.uf.tistory.com/attach/226DBB4B529B6B73235C03) would be helpful. You cac refer to the final section.

Comment: @sos440 THIS IS EXCELLENT I WISH I COULD UPVOTE THIS AS AN ANSWER.  feel free to post this as an answer, this is a keeper in my integration collection.  thank you very much for this +10.

do you use LaTex?  How do you write your integral signs?  They are not as slanted to the right as the one's on this site, instead they are straight up.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Integral_Uprightness.svg.

Comment: @sos440 Your document is very impressive.  This is the best I have seen on MathStackExchange.  Thanks.

Comment: @sos440 Could you please convert your comment to an answer? Ping me back when you're done.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ, Sorry, I forgot to respond to your comment. In fact I am making some other trials for calculating various Ahmed integrals and Coxeter integrals. So I decided not to make a formal answer before it is done or I give up.